# planning_environment: How to specify link padding post-diamondback?

Tags: ros, planning-environment, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation of the [planning_environment](http://www.ros.org/wiki/planning_environment) package states that

> "...much of the information on diamondback no longer holds"

but there is no clear distinction as to what has changed and what remains the same in the ROS API. In particular, I'm interested in knowing whether specifying individual link padding values is still supported, like so (yaml syntax):

```
default_robot_padding: 0.01
link_padding:
  - link: foo
    padding: 0.0
```

In electric's pr2_arm_navigation_actions, there exists such a [file](http://https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_arm_navigation/trunk/pr2_arm_navigation_actions/config/environment_server_padding.yaml) but seems to be unused.

TIA.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12857/planning_environment:-how-to-specify-link-padding-post-diamondback?/) by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3907 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-11-01**:
i just add the lines as you mentioned in the MyRobot_planning_description.yaml. the default_robot_padding is successfully loaded, but the link_padding for each link is not loaded. do you successfully loaded them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can still set individual link padding using the yaml method - just make sure it's getting loaded in the private namespace when you launch the environment server (or wherever else you are creating a planning_environment::CollisionModels class".  The default_robot_padding value is taken from the global namespace under /robot_description_planning/default_robot_padding - if you put it in your <your_robot>_planning_description.yaml using the auto-generated arm navigation app than things should happen correctly.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0